# Wired Network indicator while disconnected

Tags: wingpanel

I recently installed elementary loki on one of my computers. I connect to the internet through a network cable. I have an unreliable Internet and it disconnects sometimes. If it happens on Windows 7, it shows a yellow exclamation on the network adapter indicating the user lost the IP or the internet while the cable is still plugged in. However, i don't get any such information in elementary.I usually have to wait and refresh the browser multiple times to see if it came back on.
Is there a way to get some indication on the wing panel if internet disappears ?

thanks